# How to design Multiple Patch requests in WebApi Core

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi, patch

I would like to know what's the best way to design multiple updates to the resource(s) in WebApi .Net Core.

For example, I would like to enable the following features for `users` resources

- Update User Password
- Update User role
- Update User Details (such as Firstname, last name, etc.)

So, according to REST tutorials and articles, I learnt that I need to use `PATCH` method to update partial resource.

We did some discussions in the team and we are confused with these two options:

**Option 1**

implement multiple PATCH routes for different actions

- PATCH `/api/users/{id}/password`
- PATCH `/api/users/{id}/role`
- PATCH `/api/users/{id}/details`

**Option 2**

implement ONLY single PATCH action for the whole resource.  Users will send application/json-patch+json for partial updates.

- PATCH `/api/users/id`  (accepts `JsonPatchDocument` parameter)

I tried to find the best practices for Restful Route Namings and most of them only cover for simple CRUD activities or nested resources.

For this kind of multiple UPDATE operations, may I know what's the best practice for naming the routes?  Or the term for it to study in-depth?  Thanks.

Comment: Just to note, having one route/method per `PATCH` request allows for better authorization control. You can annotate each method with an `AuthorizeAttribute` with this approach to make sure only the fields you *want* to be updated are actually updated by authorized users accordingly (e.g. only admins are allowed to update user role, or in general: only <other user group> is allowed to update <field>)

Comment: I think best way is to use PUT with Option 2. For me PATCH method is something you should use with OData or something like it.

Comment: Definitely, **Option 2**. Also see how it can be implemented [here](https://github.com/Marusyk/Simple.HttpPatch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PATCH` requests are used to update parts of single resources, i.e. where only a specific subset of resource fields should be replaced. The semantic is best described as "please change the resource identified by the URL according to my change request".

- `PATCH` requests are usually applied to single resources as patching entire collection is challenging
- `PATCH` requests are usually not robust against non-existence of resource instances
- on successful `PATCH` requests, the server will update parts of the resource addressed by the URL as defined by the change request in the payload
- successful `PATCH` requests will usually generate `200` or `204` (if resources have been updated with or without updated content returned)

*Note*: since implementing `PATCH` correctly is a bit tricky, I strongly suggest to choose one and only one of the following patterns per endpoint.In preference order:

1. use `PUT` with complete objects to update a resource as long as feasible (i.e. do not use `PATCH` at all).
2. use `PATCH` with partial objects to only update parts of a resource, whenever possible. (This is basically [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396), a specialized media type `application/merge-patch+json` that is a partial resource representation.)
3. use `PATCH` with [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), a specialized media type `application/json-patch+json` that includes instructions on how to change the resource.
4. use `POST` (with a proper description of what is happening) instead of `PATCH`, if the request does not modify the resource in a way defined by the semantics of the media type.

**Option 1** seems like bad design, because you will have a lot of endpoints for each property.

**Option 2** is following by REST recommendation and specified in [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)

You can implement it in following ways:

- [Delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj890572(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (part of Microsoft ASP.NET WebAPI OData): it has some problems with numbers when using JSON. You also need to install the package with all its non-trivial dependencies;
- [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/): the client must organize the data per operation and the size of the request is not optimized.
- Use [Simple.HttpPatch](https://github.com/Marusyk/Simple.HttpPatch) that allows to easily apply partial updates
- One more [SimplePatch](https://github.com/OmarMuscatello/SimplePatch) implementation

**Route Namings**

- use plural nouns for resource name. Do not mix up singular and plural nouns. Keep it simple and use only plural nouns for all resources(`users`, instead of `user`)
- if you have two base URLs per resource then the first URL is for a collection (list); the second is for a specific element in the collection (`/users` and `/users/1`)
- if you have relations, use sub-resources for it

> /users/1/phones - returns a list of phones for user 1
> /users/1/phones/1 - returns phone #1 for user 1

- keep verbs out of your base URLs. Use HTTP request methods `GET`, `POST`, `PUT/PATCH`, `DELETE` with two base URLs to CRUD operations. The point is that developers probably don't need the documentations to understand how the API behaves.In other way you will have a long list of URLs and no consistent pattern making it difficult for developers to learn how to use your API
- complex things need to be hidden behind the `?`. Almost every API has a lot of parameters that you can read, update, filter and work with them in any other ways. But all these parameters should not be visible in the base addresses. It is best to specify the parameters within the reference to the base addresses.

> GET /users/1234?firstName=Bill&PhoneNumber="1111"

**Also see links**

- [Microsoft REST API Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md)
- [Zalando RESTful API](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/)
- [Web API Design](https://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf)

Comment: Just to add to this, https://github.com/OmarMuscatello/SimplePatch is an excellent Patch library as well